# Git: Setting the repository after changin the name in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have changed the name of a repository using bitbucket settings interface,

but now I can't push from the command line

```
remote: Repository tdkdev/tdkwebapp not found
fatal: repository 'https://nunito@bitbucket.org/tdkdev/tdkwebapp.git/' not found
```

Comment: You need to also update the url of the remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the origin upstream:

```
git push --set-upstream origin tdkdev/tdkwebapp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update where `origin` points in each copy of the repo:

`git remote set-url origin https://nunito@bitbucket.org/tdkdev/new-location.git`